# Program does not read printf and starts before main?

Tags: c, visual-studio

So I just started writing code. And after I wrote small chunk of it I went and tested what was written. And something came up, that I really don't even know how to explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct window {
    unsigned left, top;
    unsigned width, height;
    unsigned zorder;
};

/*struct kurs {
    unsigned left, top; //ok, this isn't important
};*/

int main() { 
//the program starts before int, my console window opens up
    struct window *wnd;
    //struct kurs pokazivac; this isn't important also
    int number_wnd; 
    //then it just skips to int number_wnd line, and when I try to go to next step, it stays there, console windows opens up, asking some kind of input
    //if I press enter it skips to this empty line, and if I press next step it asks me some kind of input again
    printf("Number of windows: "); //when I press eneter it comes to beginning of this line,and when I press next step it moves to scanf
    scanf("%d", &number_wnd); //when I try to go next step from beginning of this line it opens up exe.common.inl

    wnd = (struct window*)malloc(number_wnd * sizeof(struct window));
    if (wnd == NULL) {
        printf("Memory problem!");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nInsert window positions: ");
    for (int i = 0;i < number_wnd;++i) { //this isn't important also, since it doesn't even get to here
        printf("%d. WINDOW\n", i + 1);

        printf("\tleft: ");
        scanf("%u", wnd[i].left);
        printf("\ttop: ");
        scanf("%u", wnd[i].top);

        printf("\twidth: ");
        scanf("%u", wnd[i].width);
        printf("\theight: ");
        scanf("%u", wnd[i].height);

        printf("\tzorder: ");
        scanf("%u", wnd[i].zorder);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    if (wnd != NULL) {
        free(wnd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is result of my messing with code, pre-result (without /**/ on structure kurs) was even weirder. Code started at the end of that struct, and later on it would report error that I need to close left `}` even tho it was closed.

I am writing this in visual studio, and I tried it in 2 open projects.
Is my visual studio broken? Or is my code broken?

## EDIT:

So, I compiled it; and now I got error :

> LNK1104    cannot open file 'C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\VSITE\PMA\Labosi\lab10\Debug\lab10.exe'

How should I treat this? Copy paste code to new project or? This is my first time meeting with this, and I am new at programming, so I don't really have vast knowledge.

## EDIT 2:

I put `&` in `scanf`, don't even know how I overlooked that. But didn't change the problem. Code still starts before main.

Comment: If your program asks for input while you seem to be in a different line, you are probably debugging an outdated version of the code. Make sure that you compiled the correct variant. In MSVC you can compile debug and release variant. First you must ensure that compilation succeeds.

Comment: Please separate the issue with debugging and with compile error (missing closing bracket). If that issue is not present in the code you show us, it doesn't make any sense to mention it. It is simply not relevant at all if it is not happening in exactly that code.

Comment: it is useless to check `if (wnd != NULL) ` before the free, you cannot reach that position when it is null

Comment: oh I did, and I get the error : LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\VSITE\PMA\Labosi\lab10\Debug\lab10.exe'

Is maybe problem in there? I just got this? Should I create new project or?

Comment: @MarjaM. probably your program cannot be compiled because of error(s) in your sources, so the executable doesn't exist and you cannot run it.

Comment: @bruno I was doing this with other builds in my project, could it be interference? But they don't have errors, and I fixed all error's in this code

Comment: @MarjaM. if you have a way to force the build (may be delete debug & release directories ?) do that and look at the traces produced during the build to see what is (re)compiled and how the executable is made

Comment: @bruno I deleted entire file, opened new project, and pasted (unbugged) code there, and it works. Thank you a lot

Comment: There are a lot "this isn't important" in your code. If it is not, then remove it. Please provide an [mcve]. Also it looks like you want to ask two questions: one about a linker problem and another about a runtime problem. If these are two questions, then please separate them into two questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
scanf("%u", wnd[i].left); /* you are missing & */
```

you want to access `wnd[i]` but you have allocated memory only for `wnd` not for `wnd[i]`. Instead of using *structure pointer* use **array of structure pointer**. For e.g

```
struct window *wnd[number_wnd];
```

so that you can allocate memory for each `wnd` and put the data into that.

Sample code:

```
struct window {
        unsigned left, top;
        unsigned width, height;
        unsigned zorder;
};
int main(void) {

        int number_wnd;
        printf("Number of windows: \n");
        scanf("%d", &number_wnd);
        struct window *wnd[number_wnd]; /* array of structure pointer */

        printf("\nInsert window positions: ");
        for (int i = 0;i < number_wnd;++i) {
                printf("%d. WINDOW\n", i + 1);
                wnd[i] = (struct window*)malloc(sizeof(struct window)); /* for each wnd allocate memory equal to size of window */
                if (wnd[i] == NULL) {
                        printf("Memory problem!");
                        return 0;
                }

                printf("\tleft: ");
                scanf("%u", &wnd[i]->left); /* you need to give & as left is an integere */
                printf("\ttop: ");
                scanf("%u", &wnd[i]->top);

                printf("\twidth: ");
                scanf("%u", &wnd[i]->width);
                printf("\theight: ");
                scanf("%u", &wnd[i]->height);

                printf("\tzorder: ");
                scanf("%u", &wnd[i]->zorder);
                putchar('\n');
        }
        for (int i = 0;i < number_wnd;++i) {
                        free(wnd[i]); /* free each wnd */
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I cannot put "number_wnd" inside of "struct window *wnd[number_wnd];". It gives me error that expression must have constant value

Comment: And thanks for "&" been looking at code 2hr, and didn't even notice that

Comment: I deleted entire project, and started all over again, with insight in your code, with slight differences. (as I said number_wnd couldn't be put in struct window *wnd[ here ];, so I couldn't use malloc the way you showed me, but at least project compiles and starts they way it should! I still get breakpoint when I try to free it, but that is different problem, the kind I can deal with. Thanks a lot, really

Comment: Your welcome. Though I didn't experienced like `struct window *wnd[ number_wnd ];` is not allowed anywhere i.e you can take `number_wnd`  at run time and create `struct window *wnd[ number_wnd ];`

Answer (score 0):

1- i used the same code on my compiler & worked perfectly i just had to change the following

```
` 
     scanf("%u", &wnd[i].left);
     printf("\ttop: ");


    scanf("%u", &wnd[i].top);

    printf("\twidth: ");
    scanf("%u", &wnd[i].width);
    printf("\theight: ");
    scanf("%u", &wnd[i].height);

    printf("\tzorder: ");
    scanf("%u", &wnd[i].zorder);`
```

Comment: Yeah, don't know how I missed '&', been looking at code 2hrs, changed that but my code still starts before main.. could it be compiler problem?

Comment: try delete the release & debug files in the bin file & run it again

Comment: yes. Well in fact I deleted entire project, and started all over again, and it compiles and starts as it should. It still triggeres breakpoint when I try to free memory, but I can deal with that. 
What do you think triggered this problem at first? My missing of '&'s? Is that possible? Thanks, a lot.

Comment: yes i think one of the executions crashed(due to the missing '&') and never really considered as finished so you cant overwrite it